# Migration from Steema Teechart .Net 4.0.2009.42283 to 4.1.2011.4197 makes many properties unavailable.What can be the workaround?

Tags: silverlight, teechart

1.Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Tools.RectangleTool' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
2.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Tools.ColorLine' does not contain a definition for 'UpdateLayout'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
3.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Styles.Series' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
4.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Tools.Annotation' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
5.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Chart' does not contain a definition for 'Margin'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
6.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Chart' does not contain a definition for 'MouseMove'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?
7.'Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Tools.CursorTool' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.What can be the alternative for this property in 2011 TeeChart .Net dll?

Comment: do you have any teechart code that was helpful to you before this change and which now isn't?

Answer (score 1):

The TeeBase class doesn't inherit from Control anymore in TeeChart Silverlight to improve the performance. This change makes some of its descendants to loose some FrameworkElement and UIElement properties like those you mentioned. I've added it to the wish list to be revised (TW16016314).

In the meanwhile, I only can think on creating the desired properties manually.

Steema Software.